# SQLDataReader does not identify the empty columns

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, dbnull

So, I have a function which reads the result of a query that is used later on the program as it follows:

```
connection.Open();
int combination;
using (SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand())
{
    com1.Connection = connection; 
    com1.CommandText = "select FinalComboId from relationTable where sourceCombo=@source and destinationCombo=@destination";
    com1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@source",combo.ToString() ?? ""));
    com1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@destination", destination ?? ""));
    SqlDataReader comboLinkReader = com1.ExecuteReader();
    if (!comboLinkReader.Read() || comboLinkReader.FieldCount==0)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(),
                   "alertMessage", @"alert('Combination does not exists,please contact admin!')", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        combination = Convert.ToInt32(comboLinkReader["FinalComboId"]);

    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is: if the result is empty, than execute the alert script, else save the result as an integer, that will be used for further calculations. I have followed several tutorials and examples regarding that issue, and when I executed the function the other day, it worked just fine. Now, 2 hours from launching it to production, it does not calculate the first condition:

```
if (!comboLinkReader.Read() || comboLinkReader.FieldCount==0)
       {//calculations  here}
```

I have also tried with

```
if (!comboLinkReader.Read() || comboLinkReader.IsDbNull(0))
   {//calculations}
```

and I have the same problem. The query should return one single value.
Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: `IsDbNull` is a method that needs an argument for the column index.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I am editing the question, forgot the index

Comment: What actually happens, then?

Comment: How do you know there are no results? Did you debug the code? If `Read` returns true when you didn't expect it, what are the contents of the row it loaded? There's no reason to count fields or check for nulls (unless you *have* stored nulls in this field)

Comment: In theory, it should fire the alert script if the result of the query is null or it has no value, else it should return the value. What actually happens, is that sometimes, the first condition is not executed, event though the query has no results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have created a situation where the value of the query is Null, and the reader shows always FieldCount=0

Comment: @Ange1 there's no "in theory". If `Read` returns true, it's because it read a row. Most likely, the second condition in OR doesn't do what you think it does. Even with no rows, the reader *does* have one field. `IsDbNull` returns true only if there *is* a null value, false in every other case - including no existing rows

Comment: @Ange1 post a reproducible example. Or reverse the conditions.  I'll bet that if you use Tim Schmelter's code you'll see that the alert will be called.

Comment: Note that this code is pointless: `combo.ToString() ?? ""`. `ToString` would cause a `NullRefernceException` if `combo` was `null`. So the null-coalescing operator is never used. What type is `combo` at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have removed the `combo.ToString() ?? ""` . combo is a int variable, and I need to convert it to String before passing it to the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IsDbNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method that needs an argument for the column index.

```
int? finalComboId = null;
if(comboLinkReader.Read() && !comboLinkReader.IsDbNull(0))
    finalComboId = comboLinkReader.GetInt32(0);
if(!finalComboId.HasValue)
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", @"alert('Combination does not exists,please contact admin!')", true);
else 
    combination = finalComboId.Value;
```

Comment: With this piece of code, comboLinkReader.Read() shows empty results (as it should). However, even the script is hit (after putting a  breakpoint) , it does not appear in the screen. Maybe there is some condition I am missing?

Comment: What means _"comboLinkReader.Read() shows empty results"_? You know that you have to show the page to the client to see the `alert`? You are currently at the server and the `alert` is a javascript function that is executed when the document loads.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint on comboLinkReader and open the  "properties" , it shows at the Result View properties : Empty "Enumeration generated no results"

Comment: @Ange1: which property shows that? It's not clear what's wrong. Where have you set the breakpoint exactly?

Comment: Do you think that I should put the alert on Client Side instead of server side? I have other pages where scripts are generated on server side, and they all worked fine. The breakpoint is at ` finalComboId = comboLinkReader.GetInt32(0);` , in order to see the comboLinkReader values

Comment: If you've set the breakpoint there **and it got hit** then there was an result and it was not null, so `comboLinkReader.GetInt32(0)` should return an integer. You have to set another breakpoint behind this line to inspect `finalComboId.Value`. The variable `combination` should also get a value in the `else` block.  This doesn't happen?

Comment: @Ange1: it's ok to register the `alert` on serverside because thast's the only place where you can do that(because theres the database). But you won't see the alert until the page is not rendered to the client.

Comment: after putting breakpoints in all the lines, to check the values, I see that after the first call: `if(comboLinkReader.Read() && !comboLinkReader.IsDbNull(0))` the value of finalComboId is null. So the problem should be with rendering the page to the client. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: @Ange1: you still seem to be confused where to put your breakpoints. If you set it above `if(comboLinkReader.Read() && !comboLinkReader.IsDbNull(0))` of course `finalComboId` is null because it is initialized in the next line. But even if you set the breakpoint there it will be unassigned because you can evaluate the assigned value one line after it was assigned not in the same line. What is the value of `combination`(or `finalComboId.Value`) at the end?

Comment: It is always null, it actually hits the `if(!finalComboId.HasValue)
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", @"alert('Combination does not exists,please contact admin!')", true); `  line.

Comment: Ok, then all is fine but the alert isn't shown when the page is rendered? Do you redirect to a different page later? Do you use a `Scriptmanager` at all?

Comment: Exactly, the alert isn't shown, and I do not redirect to another page, so it probably is a problem of javascript. I am trying to investigate further with firebug to see if there is any error

Comment: Ok, if it doesn't work  write a very simple sample page and put in in `Page_Load`. If it still doesn't work ask another question on stackoverflow regarding this issue. It may be related to ASP.NET ajax and UpdatePanels. Is it an asynchonous postback?

Comment: Another question, the script should be fired on a button click event. Probably this is the problem?

Comment: @Ange1: the script isnt fired directly when you click at the button. I assume that your code is in the button-click event handler. Then registering this script won't execute it immediately. It will be executed when the browser renders the posted HTML. I guess your issue is related to `UpdatePanels`. Maybe you need to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanelId,updatePanelId.GetType(), "alert", ......., true);`

Comment: I found the problem. Firefox does not recognize the '@' character on `"@alert('Combination does not exists,please contact admin!')"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91593/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-ange1).