# ADO SqlReader fails after read()=true: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have the following piece of code (modified after some answers):

```
  String sql = "SELECT invoice_pk FROM invoices WHERE invoice_number = " + InvoiceNumberLabel.Text;
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, invoiceHeaderOnOSDconn);
  SqlDataReader invoiceResult = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if (invoiceResult.HasRows)
  {
     if (invoiceResult.Read())
     {  // As Rahul suggested (even though the post is now deleted) I added this third check and it worked
        if (invoiceResult["invoice_pk"] != DBNull.Value)
        { 
           String invoice_pk = invoiceResult["invoice_pk"].ToString();
        }
     }
     invoiceResult.Close();
  }
```

As far as I know, it shouldn't fail because I am double checking the result, first with "HasRows" and next with if "Read()".
Now, although the code works I am more confused than before, because with the same values it started to work.

Could somebody tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message?  Is `invoiceResult["invoice_pk"]` null?

Comment: Note also that appending a string to your SQL (especially a value from a text box) leaves you vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Consider switching to parameters instead.

Comment: thank you very much for you reply. The error that I have is: 
  Message=Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: Also consider putting the `SqlDataReader` in `using` statement (really put all `IDisposable`s)

Comment: Are you certain you have no other code that has been removed - you just have the one line inside the `if` statement?  I ask that because you're setting a variable but not doing anything with it.

Comment: Just for grins, try `invoice_pk = invoiceResult.GetValue(0).ToString();`

Comment: @MiguelMezquita:- Your error shows the problem of `invoiceResult.Read()` but since you are already checking it then that does not make much sense.

Comment: `if (invoiceResult.HasRows)` is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: try [IsDbNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), refer to answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988881/sqldatareader-does-not-identify-the-empty-columns).

Comment: @DStanley I use it more often like this: `String invoice_pk = invoiceResult["invoice_pk"] as string` ,is the only way that never fails to get read

Comment: @ D Stanley: Yes, I am pretty sure. What you see now is all that I have done during the troubleshooting process. The value on the label, for example, comes from a label inside a template. At that point I thought that the logic could not reach the value inside of the template. Also, the query was different but I modified it to be sure that the field name was correct. I copypasted the field name from SQL Server Manager, just to be sure that it was correct.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoiceResult.GetString() with column idx or column name.

Comment: @ juharr: Thanks for your suggestion. I am doing it right now.